# css animations on rotated objects

Tags: html, css

I apply rotation on the element and on hovering over it, i apply animation. The problem is, on hover, element comes back to its original position and then animate and then after animation it comes back to rotated position. I don't want that element to come back to its original position but it should stay on the rotated position. One thing more, I will vary rotation from javascript also, so it wont be fixed, hence it shouldn't be a part of animation. Here is my code:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-grow {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
}
@keyframes hvr-grow {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
}
.block{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin:30px;
}

.block:hover{
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: `I don't want that element comes to its original position but it should animate on the rotated position`.?? you want it to  go back to the original position after animation?

Comment: NO. I don't want that element go back to its original position.

Answer (score 0):

You should also include the rotation on the keyframes. Here's your updated fiddle.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-grow {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.4);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.4);
  }
}
@keyframes hvr-grow {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.4);
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.4);
  }
}
.block{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin:30px;
}

.block:hover{
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: I varies rotation from javascript, so it wont be fixed, hence it shouldn't be a part of animation.

Comment: @AbdullahDanyal what if like this. you put the element inside a wrapper. rotate the element using javascript. then put the hover scale animation on the wrapper

Comment: That's really a nice idea :) I will try

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think You should use javascript to get this effect because element lose his ":hover" pseudoclass when You move your mouse away from it that's why it's going back. The fill-mode only works while mouse is still on element. Hope it will help.

Snippet:

```js
$("#block").hover(function() {
  $("#block").addClass("rotate");
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-grow {
  0% {}
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4) rotate(45deg);
    transform: scale(1.4) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-grow {
  0% {}
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4) rotate(45deg);
    transform: scale(1.4) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px;
}

.rotate {
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/OfftheCode/pen/NjeERL)